# Linked list implementation in python

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I am learning how to use linked lists, and would like to add a value, remove a value, and test if a value is in the linked list. I am struggling to work out how test for a value and remove a value.

```
class Node(object):
   def __init__(self, v, n):
      self.value = v
      self.next = n

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstLink = None
    def add (self, newElement):
        self.firstLink = Node(newElement, self.firstLink)
    def test(self, testValue):

    def remove(self, testValue):
```

Comment: What are you struggling with and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a value is in a LinkedList you have to go through the list and check every item

```
def contains(self, testValue):
    ptr = self.firstLink
    while ptr != None:
        if ptr.value == testValue:
            return True
        ptr = ptr.next
    return False
```

When using **remove()** method you usually don't pick an item to be removed. Remove method should only remove the last item added to LinkedList. Last in, First out.

```
def remove(self):
    if self.firstLink == None():
        return None
    else:
        item = self.firstLink.value
        self.firstLink = self.firstLink.next
        return item
```

To learn more about Linked Lists or see how can 'remove element' from LinkedList be implemented in python go to this site. It is well explained in there [LinkedList](https://dbader.org/blog/python-linked-list)

Comment: Thank you! The site was very useful aswell.

Comment: @Greta Glad I could help